# Which function is used for posting in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, posts

In my Wordpress site users are unable to do any post. They saved in draft but not publish.
Please give any suggestions.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

I think `wp_insert_post()` is used for posting. I am new in wordpress please help me.

Comment: yes you  can user  this with all the parameter   wp_insert_post()

Comment: pass the status of post  publish in function parameter

Comment: Basically i have a plugin in theme that is important for theme's functionality , after activating this plugin users are unable to publish any post just saved in draft , so please tell me ,what is good for me.

Comment: yes for the review and security reason plugin working accordingly if you want to post directly  deactivate   the plugin

Comment: Sorry, this plugin included with theme that is a paid theme, so please give any idea without deactivating the plugin.

Comment: have you check my  below code  i posted in answer ?

Comment: Yes, I have to use this in register_post_type () , the post status and others in post.php file?

Comment: you can create new template for this and   use this in that also

Comment: Any one please help me.

Comment: I don't get the solution,how to insert data in database they are not saving,just going to draft as a status.

Comment: kindly post the code you are useing  for this act

Answer (score 1):

```
$post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'post name',
  'post_content'  => 'This post.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array('cat id')
);
    wp_insert_post( $post );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take look into settings - general and check your timezone! It should be something like UTC+0, NOT e.g. Berlin, Zagreb, etc.

I had the same issue after hours of debugging and at least, I changed the timezone to UTC+0 and it worked.

see also: [Wordpress admin cannot publish posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42776296/wordpress-admin-cannot-publish-posts/52366479#52366479)