# Wordpress admin cannot publish posts

Tags: wordpress

I have Wordpress installed on my local wamp platform. I used it for a while without any problem. However today without any unusual change I am not able to publish any pages/posts anymore.
I am the only user in wordpress with admin rights.

I thought it might be corrupted, so I installed a fresh Wordpress instance. Did not change anything, no plugins, just went directly to posts to publish, but it is not in the dropdown list, I can select only '**Pending Review**' and '**Draft**'.

To be even more strange, same time this happened in my live site as well. I am on a shared hosting environment, so totally different space from my localhost. (Though code was copied from localhost to production.)

Has anybody experienced similar in the past?

Comment: Had this happen some months ago. Seems it was related to a plugin update. I disabled all plugins and publish option returned. Took time to re-enable one by one, checking each time but never found culprit. BUT, the publish button remained working...

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought, and that is why I tried it with a fresh Wordpress install, and it did not work. There were not any plugins or custom code, just the pure fresh Wordpress install, and there were no 'Publish' possibility on the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Please take look into settings - general and check your timezone!
It should be something like UTC+0, NOT e.g. Berlin, Zagreb, etc.

I had the same issue after hours of debugging and at least, I changed the timezone to UTC+0 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitly time related. I have the same issue after messing with my php.ini's and timezome's. Also I installed NTPd and changed the hardware clock.