# WordPress Customizer - Publish button stays active

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress Customizer is not working normally. When I click on "Save & Publish" it saved the value but still stays active. I tried to update WP to 4.9 but the problem remains the same.

When I click on checkbox admin-ajax.php works and returns:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"setting_validities":{"top_bar_enable":true},"changeset_status":"auto-draft"
,"autosaved":true}}
```

When I click on Save admin-ajax.php works again

```
{"success":true,"data":{"setting_validities":{"top_bar_enable":true},"changeset_status":null
}}
```

I installed the theme to a new WordPress installation and it works great. Is there any ideas how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be like my answer on [Wordpress admin cannot publish posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42776296/wordpress-admin-cannot-publish-posts/52366479#52366479)

Please take look into settings - general and check your timezone!
It should be something like UTC+0, NOT e.g. Berlin, Zagreb, etc.

I had the same issue after hours of debugging and at least, I changed the timezone to UTC+0 and it worked.

Comment: How do you know the problem is time-related?

Comment: I tried many things the last hours to fix a similiar problem and found many threads like this (on other forums), so I do not know exactly, if the same problem causes this error, but please try it.